# Could a subspace of a normed linear space be not a linear subspace?

Tags: terminology, vector-spaces

On page 38, Functional Analysis, Pater Lax:

> Let $X$ be a normed linear space, $Y$ a subspace of $X$, The closure of $Y$ is a linear subspace of $X$.

But on Wikipedia, [linear subspace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_subspace:)

> A linear subspace is usually called simply a subspace when the context serves to distinguish it from other kinds of subspaces.

I'm confused on the wording. What's the difference between subspace and linear subspace in Lax's book? Could a subspace of a normed linear space be not a linear subspace?

Comment: The point is that the topological closure of a subspace is also a subspace. There is no reason to expect this should happen, but it does.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference: in functional analysis a subspace is intended as a linear subspace.

The only other subspaces you may have are topological subspaces: to avoid confusion you call them just subsets.